# Xarray conditional subsetting based on index

Tags: python, python-xarray

Let's say I have a `xr.DataArray` **A** with three dimensions (`time`,`lon`,`lat`) containing some random data. Now I have a second`xr.DataArray` **B** with two dimensions (`lon`,`lat`) having the same grid as **A**. The values of **B** represent the integer-based `time` index of **A**.

How can I subset **A** based on the integer values present in **B**?

That is, I want to get the values of **A** where the integer index of the `time` coordinate equals the values of **B**.

## MWE

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

A = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(10,5,5),
                 dims=['time','lon','lat'], 
                 coords={'time':pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=10),
                         'lon':np.arange(1,6),
                         'lat':np.arange(1,6)
                         }
                  )

B = xr.DataArray(np.random.randint(0,9,(5,5)),
                 dims=['lon','lat'], 
                 coords={'lon':np.arange(1,6),
                         'lat':np.arange(1,6)
                         }
                  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clear example.

IIUC, you want to use the value in `B` to select the index of the time coord of `A`:

```py
In [9]: A.isel(time=B)
Out[9]:
<xarray.DataArray (lon: 5, lat: 5)>
array([[ 1.01208355,  1.29773366,  0.53875951,  2.45590211,  0.49782187],
       [-1.25561793,  1.00070962,  1.39388746, -0.88571071, -0.58113385],
       [ 1.21686752, -1.71612589,  0.08652589,  0.12663398,  0.4425077 ],
       [ 1.65911561, -0.41454701, -0.69167209,  0.59707559,  0.64610678],
       [ 0.7255797 ,  1.27375691, -0.10813576, -0.94236789,  1.53208474]])
Coordinates:
    time     (lon, lat) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-04 ... 2000-01-08
  * lon      (lon) int64 1 2 3 4 5
  * lat      (lat) int64 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Easy as that, `xarray` is  really great. Just a follow-up question: Is there a way of masking out (e.g. as `np.nan`) all values up to that specific index?

Comment: I'm a beginner with xarray too, but maybe `A.where` is what you need. That being said, I couldnt get it to work :D